What order are Sapiens, Homo Deus, and 21 Lessons for the 21st Century intended to be read in?
I've already read Sapiens, and I am moving onto Homo Deus. But this got me thinking: Since Sapiens, 21 Lessons, and Homo Deus are viewed as a trilogy of past, present, and future, is there an ideal read order? The first order that came to my mind was reading past, present, then future in chronological order. But another order could be past, future, then present, to see how the past and the future all relate to the present. Is there a recommended or official reading order for these?

The order of sapiens, Homo, is Primates. Or was this not the question?

That answers the first four words!
